# Sympy.solve provides "AttributeError"

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

If `sigma[i, j] == 0 or sigma[i, j] == 1` it doesnt matter. It only takes the position of non-zero elements. There is a code that provides finding coeffs `y1, y2, w1, w2`, which are `sympy.symbols`, of func `f` by `sympy.solve`. `C` - is a matrix.

[image]

The process of creating C-matrix:

```
w = np.array([[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]])
A = np.array([[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]])
chi = np.array([[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]])

ksi = w.dot(A)
d = int(np.linalg.det(w))
ksi_wavy = ksi - d * chi
b1 = -d * np.eye(3)
b2 = ksi
b3 = ksi_wavy.astype(int)

C = np.vstack((-b1, -b2, b3)).astype(int)
```

What about sigma is the long process, but it uses `np.array` and `np.append`.

The code:

```
import numpy as np
from sympy import *


def f(s, new_line_1, k, new_line_2):
    return np.dot(y1, C[s, :]) + np.dot(y2, new_line_1) - np.dot(w1, C[k, :]) - np.dot(w2, new_line_2)


new_line_1 = np.zeros([1, len(C[0, :])]).astype(int)
new_line_2 = np.zeros([1, len(C[0, :])]).astype(int)
intersection_1 = []  # The list of intersections
intersection_2 = []  # The list of intersections

for i in np.arange(len(sigma[:, ]) - 1):
    for t in np.arange(i + 1, len(sigma[:, ])):
        for j in np.arange(len(sigma[0, :])):
            if sigma[i, j] != 0:
                if s == -1:
                    s = j
                    intersection_1.append(s)
                else:
                    new_line_1 += C[j, :]
                    intersection_1.append(j)
            if sigma[t, j] != 0:
                if k == -1:
                    k = j
                    intersection_2.append(k)
                else:
                    new_line_2 += C[j, :]
                    intersection_2.append(j)
        solution = solve(f(s, new_line_1, k, new_line_2), [y1, y2, w1, w2])
```

In result there is an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\PythonAssignments\Python3.9\VKR.py", line 307, in <module>
    solution = solve(f(s, new_line_1, k, new_line_2), [y1, y2, w1, w2])
  File "D:\PythonAssignments\Python3.9\Python\lib\site-packages\sympy\solvers\solvers.py", line 1097, in solve
    solution = _solve_system(f, symbols, **flags)
  File "D:\PythonAssignments\Python3.9\Python\lib\site-packages\sympy\solvers\solvers.py", line 1797, in _solve_system
    i, d = _invert(g, *symbols)
  File "D:\PythonAssignments\Python3.9\Python\lib\site-packages\sympy\solvers\solvers.py", line 3028, in _invert
    indep, dep = lhs.as_independent(*symbols)
AttributeError: 'ImmutableDenseNDimArray' object has no attribute 'as_independent'
```

Can someone help what is the cause of the error? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: From the traceback I'd say the object you pass to `sympy.solve` is not the kind of `sympy` expression that it expects.  `attribute error` usually means you are trying to use the wrong method on the wrong kind of object.  It looks like `f(...)` is a numpy array.  `sympy.solve` is not designed to work with that.  More generally, mixing `numpy` and `sympy` is tricky, and shouldn't be tried without a thorough knowledge of both (at least of how they interact).

Comment: It you want more help, you need to either show all the inputs to `solve`, or make it easy to recreate that call.  We can only get so far by just reading your code!

Comment: @hpaulj, ok wait a sec, thank you

Comment: @hpaulj, I ve added more information. The whole programm "np" was used as library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you weren't providing the information I asked for, I tried to write a small test case, seeking to get at the core of your problem.

Mixing `numpy` and `sympy` is tricky and somewhat unpredictable.  But sometimes `sympy` symbols can be used in `numpy` expressions.

```
In [24]: X = np.dot(x,np.arange(3))+np.dot(y,np.array([3,2,1]))

In [25]: X
Out[25]: array([3*y, x + 2*y, 2*x + y], dtype=object)
```

Here `x` and `y` are symbols (in an `isympy` session).  `X` is a numpy array, object dtype.  The elements are sympy expressions.  This works because symbols have basic math methods such as sum and multiply.  But don't try this with expressions that involves functions like `sin` and `exp`.

And somewhat to my surprise, solve does work with this array.

```
In [26]: solve(X, [x,y])
Out[26]: {x: 0, y: 0}
```

I think `solve` just treats the array as a list, `solve(list(X), [x,y])`.  `solve` docs has a number of examples where `f` is a list (or tuple) of sympy expressions.

```
In [36]: list(X)
Out[36]: [3⋅y, x + 2⋅y, 2⋅x + y]
```

But your `f` involves some 2d arrays.

```
In [27]: X = np.dot(x,np.arange(3))+np.dot(y,np.array([[3,2,1]]))

In [28]: X
Out[28]: array([[3*y, x + 2*y, 2*x + y]], dtype=object)
```

So this `X` is (1,3) shape.

```
In [29]: solve(X, [x,y])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-b21e864fb1eb> in <module>
----> 1 solve(X, [x,y])

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sympy/solvers/solvers.py in solve(f, *symbols, **flags)
   1095         solution = _solve(f[0], *symbols, **flags)
   1096     else:
-> 1097         solution = _solve_system(f, symbols, **flags)
   1098 
   1099     #

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sympy/solvers/solvers.py in _solve_system(exprs, symbols, **flags)
   1795     for j, g in enumerate(exprs):
   1796         dens.update(_simple_dens(g, symbols))
-> 1797         i, d = _invert(g, *symbols)
   1798         g = d - i
   1799         g = g.as_numer_denom()[0]

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sympy/solvers/solvers.py in _invert(eq, *symbols, **kwargs)
   3026         was = lhs
   3027         while True:
-> 3028             indep, dep = lhs.as_independent(*symbols)
   3029 
   3030             # dep + indep == rhs

AttributeError: 'ImmutableDenseNDimArray' object has no attribute 'as_independent'
```

Now `X`

```
In [34]: list(X)
Out[34]: [array([3*y, x + 2*y, 2*x + y], dtype=object)]
```

This is not a list of sympy expressions.

Comment: I'd like to express my gratitude for your help. It really takes place and I found my mistake. I appreciate it.